Counterexample to flat base change for $\mathcal{O}_X$-modules
Consider a cartesian diagram
$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
X' @>{f'}>> X\\
@V{p'} VV @VV{p} V\\
S' @>{f}>> S
\end{CD}$$
of schemes (or even locally ringed spaces). If $\mathcal{F}$ is any $\mathcal{O}_X$-module, then there is a base change morphism
$$ f^* R^i p_* \mathcal F \to R^i(p')_* (f')^* \mathcal F.   $$
The flat base change theorem says that if all objects are schemes, $f$ is flat, and $\mathcal F$ is quasicoherent, then base change is an isomorphism. Is there a nice counterexample if $\mathcal F$ is not quasicoherent?

To apply base change theorems one needs the diagram to be not just commutative but Cartesian.

Sorry, misspoke. Thanks for the correction

I think that the following might be a counterexample. Take $S = \mathrm{Spec}(\mathbb{R})$ and $X = \mathbb{A}^1_{\mathbb{R}}$. I will take $S' - \mathrm{Spec}(\mathbb{C})$, so $X' = \mathbb{A}^1_{\mathbb{C}}$. Consider the point $x: \mathrm{Spec}(\mathbb{R}[t]/(t^2+1)) \to \mathbb{A}^1_{\mathbb{R}}$. Let $\mathcal{F}$ be the sheaf of $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{A}^1_{\mathbb{R}}}$-modules defined as follows for opens $U \subset \mathbb{A}^1_{\mathbb{R}}$:
$$ \mathcal{F}(U) = \begin{cases} 0 \; \text{ if $x \notin U$} \\ \mathbb{R}[t]_{(t^2+1)} \; \text{ if $x \in U$} \end{cases} $$
(Note that this is actually a sheaf of $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{A}^1_{\mathbb{R}}}$-algebras in the evident way).
The pushforward $p_*(\mathcal{F})$ can be viewed as the $\mathbb{R}$-algebra $\mathbb{R}[t]_{(t^2+1)}$. The pullback $f^*p_*(\mathcal{F})$ is the base change $\mathbb{C}$-algebra $A:= \mathbb{C} \otimes_{\mathbb{R}} \mathbb{R}[t]_{(t^2+1)}$. Note that $A$ is a localization of $\mathbb{C}[t]$, and so it is a domain.
Let $x_1, x_2 \in \mathbb{A}^1_{\mathbb{C}}$ be the two preimages of $x$ (corresponding to $\pm \sqrt{-1}$). I think that the pullback $(f')^*(\mathcal{F})$ is the sheafification of the following presheaf $\mathcal{G}$ of $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{A}_{\mathbb{C}}^1}$-algebras:
$$ \mathcal{G}(V) = \begin{cases} A \; \text{ if $x_1 \in V$ and $x_2 \in V$} \\ A_{(t-t(x_1))} \; \text{ if $x_1 \in V$ and $x_2 \notin V$}\\ A_{(t-t(x_2))} \; \text{ if $x_2 \in V$ and $x_1 \notin V$} \\ 0 \; \text{ otherwise} \end{cases} $$
I believe that the sheafification is the following:
$$ (f')^*(\mathcal{F})(V) = \begin{cases} A_{(t-t(x_1))} \times A_{(t-t(x_2))} \; \text{ if $x_1 \in V$ and $x_2 \in V$} \\ A_{(t-t(x_1))} \; \text{ if $x_1 \in V$ and $x_2 \notin V$}\\ A_{(t-t(x_2))} \; \text{ if $x_2 \in V$ and $x_1 \notin V$}\\ 0 \; \text{ otherwise} \end{cases} $$
Therefore, the pushforward $(p')_*((f')^*(\mathcal{F}))$ is the product $A_{(t-t(x_1))} \times A_{(t-t(x_2))}$, which is not a domain. I believe that the base change map is given by the diagonal $A \to A_{(t-t(x_1))} \times A_{(t-t(x_2))}$, so it is not an isomorphism.
(Edited: corrected the computation of the pullback).

Very nice. There is a closely related (but non-finite type) situation that's easier to describe: set $Y=\operatorname{Spec}\mathcal O_{X,x}$, and $\mathscr G=i_i^{-1}\mathcal O_Y$ where $i \colon x \hookrightarrow Y$ is the closed point (which is an $\mathcal O_Y$-algebra via the unit of $i^{-1}\dashv i_$). Note that it is $i^{-1}$ and not $i^*$, so $\mathscr G$ is not quasi-coherent. The base change $Y'$ is now only semilocal, and everything is supported at the closed points. That's a clean way to see the product pop out. Your $\mathscr F$ is the pushforward of $\mathscr G$ along $Y\to X$.

Yes! This is how I was secretly thinking about it. With this language, I think that one can globalize the example above, if we want to work with complex varieties. Let S be an elliptic curve, and L be a 2-torsion line bundle. Let X be the total space of L, and take $S' \to S$ be the etale 2-cover corresponding to L. Inside of X, you have a closed immersion $i:Y \hookrightarrow X$ where $Y$ is again the 2-cover. You can let $\mathcal{F}=i_*i^{-1}\mathcal{O}_X$. The main point is that the base change $X'$ remains irreducible, but the preimage of $Y$ becomes two copies of $S'$.
